# Between two numbers validation in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am trying to write a validation which performs like similar to `between` .

I am having a textbox and i want show error message if he failed to enter anything other than the given range .

**ViewModel :**

```
var vm = function viewModel()
{
var self = this;
self.mainamount=ko.observable();
self.amount1=ko.observable(2); // this will be dynamic
self.amount2=ko.observable(100)

self.validation = ko.validatedObservable({
self.mainamount.extend({required:true,number:true,min:self.amount1,max:self.amount2})  
});
}
```

I tought min and max together acts like between but i'm wrong and i am unable to work it out .

I gave a tought to try something like this

```
validator:{validation:function(param1,param2,param3){ //logic here },
message:'enter between these ..',
params: // here i am unable to pass multiple paramters 
}
```

**Reference :** [Click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/793259/Using-Observable-And-Computed-for-Validation-in-Kn) . In this article at last there is some custom way to do things but i am confused in `return` statement inside computed .

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: If you scope the validation correctly you'll have access to `self.amount1` inside the validator. Could you edit the question and add a minimal repro representative of your situation? That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: yah yes i'm really stupid not to notice such small thing . thanks for the clue in @Jeroen

Comment: Ain't no thing, glad I could help, and glad to hear your issue's resolved!